# Examples of real world big data open source applications

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-spark, mahout

I am trying to find any open source big data application, but the only stuff I found was basic examples like word count and so on. Can anyone advise where I can find what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to search if someone is providing such things. For example, [Wikipedia](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents#enwiki) does. Weather data is also a famous candidate and one quick search gives: [National Weather Service](http://water.weather.gov/precip/download.php). Just search for data you want to harvest.
Could be tweets, weather information, cars sales, usenet archive, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a number of practical examples of using Map-Reduce in real life [here](http://www.mmds.org/). Check the chapter 2 of the newest edition of this book.